# "Oddly enough, you can only explain the problem after it has happened!"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've seen a single English word (in my dictionary) that means to ridicule those, especially researchers and scientists, who can only explain a problem or phenomenon... AFTER it has happened, i.e they cannot make predictions of it, but can provide some explanations that make sense. In some cases, the explanations may not match the nature of the problem (!)

I remember exactly that word has come across my life, but now I couldn't find it again. Tried several minutes searching the web with the word's meaning, but Google seems to misunderstand me and display some unrelated stuff.

**EDIT**: The guys that commented below gave me the correct answer and also some useful alternatives (I've written an acknowledgement below too.):

- **in/with hindsight** is what I had been looking for.
- **to second-guess**.
- **to be wise after the event**, which has a close meaning.
- **Monday-morning quarterback** (noun, phr.), which is a person who likes to *second-guess*.
- **l'esprit de l'escalier**, a related French term used in English for the predicament of thinking of the perfect reply too late (Wikipedia).

Comment: Does the word in question *criticize* (_verb_) researchers and scientists, or *describe*  (_adj./noun_) researchers and scientists?

Comment: *In/with hindsight* or  *post hoc*?

Comment: We often say that "hindsight is 20/20". A related phrase is "l'esprit de l'escalier", referring to the response that one thinks of after the relevant situation is over.

Comment: I cannot answer definitively but try looking for synonyms of "lampoon" and see if there is anything there that stimulates your memory.

Comment: Would "second-guesser", "monday-morning quarterback", "hindsight critic" come in handy?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan has the adage I'd usually use. Or 'It's easy to be wise after the event.'

Comment: Perhaps something that can be said or done only *in  retrospect.*

Comment: prediction versus postdiction.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot tag more than one person (maybe due to low reputation score), so thank you DjinTonic, Eugene and Edwin Ashworth for those excellent phrases/structures. I've appended your answers to my question above.

Comment: Not to go too far down a rabbit-hole, but this reminds me of Karl Popper's criterion of "falsifiability". He distinguished scientific explanations from, say, religious explanations, because observations and experiments could falsify them. Like Newton's law of gravitation failing for the orbit of Mercury, as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you should show us how you'd like to use the word or phrase.  I hope you'll edit the question and share this.

If I assume that whatever these researchers are observing is inherently hard to predict, then you could use

**nondeterministic** or **non-predictive**

Here's what I found at Yourdictionary.com:

> - Non-predictive. Referring to the inability to objectively predict an    outcome or result of a process due to lack of knowledge of a
>   cause    and effect relationship or the inability to know initial
>   conditions.
> - In telecommunications switching and routing, the unpredictability of    a path between nodes. See also node, path, route, and switch.
> - In local area networks (LANs) a contentious medium access control    (MAC) technique that does not allow a node to predict when it will be
>   allowed to gain access to the network. Carrier sense multiple access (CSMA), which is used in 802.3 Ethernets, is non-deterministic. See also 802.3, CSMA, deterministic, LAN, MAC, and node.
> - (computer science) Exhibiting nondeterminism; involving choices    between indistinguishable possibilities. Nondeterministic bottom-up tree automaton recognize the class of regular tree languages.

Comment: These words describe the (almost) absolute inability to predict the situation. But I want to find some words that describe or even criticize those who always tell the solution after the situation has taken place. Anyway, thank you for your effort. I've appended some suggestions to my original question.

Comment: @VuTungLam - I'd still like to see a sample sentence or two showing how you'd like to use it.  Maybe *A: How was the seminar yesterday?  B: Just the usual armchair analysis, only describing what happened after the fact.*